# How to fix conversion error in a constructor in one of my used arduino libraries

Tags: c++, arduino, mqtt, esp32

I am trying to get two LoRa-esp32 to communicate with each other, but my "MASTER" needs to send the reading on the sensors received from "SLAVE" to my MQTT server (using io.adafruit). And I am not able to send the data to the MQTT server for some reason. I tried everything and I don't understand why does it happen.

I read the .h constructors of the function and I don't seem to get what's the problem with that.

This is the code i have for the publish function:

```
if (! Text1.publish(msg)) {
  Serial.println(F("Failed"));
} else {
  Serial.println(F("OK!"));
}
```

And this is the correspondent Adafruit_MQTT.h lib code:

```
class Adafruit_MQTT_Publish {
 public:
  Adafruit_MQTT_Publish(Adafruit_MQTT *mqttserver, const char *feed, uint8_t qos = 0);

  bool publish(const char *s);
  bool publish(double f, uint8_t precision=2);  // Precision controls the minimum number of digits after decimal.
                                                // This might be ignored and a higher precision value sent.
  bool publish(int32_t i);
  bool publish(uint32_t i);
  bool publish(uint8_t *b, uint16_t bLen);


private:
  Adafruit_MQTT *mqtt;
  const char *topic;
  uint8_t qos;
};
```

> This is the error I get:
>
> > Master:189:42: error: cannot convert 'String' to 'const char*' in initialization
> >
> > const char *msg = createJsonString();
> >
> > exit status 1
> >     cannot convert 'String' to 'const char*' in initialization

### EDIT

as asked in the comments to add the code in Master:168 to Master:202

```
void receive(){
  //Tentamos ler o pacote
  int packetSize = LoRa.parsePacket();

  //Verificamos se o pacote tem o tamanho mínimo de caracteres que esperamos
  if (packetSize > SETDATA.length()){
    String received = "";
    //Armazena os dados do pacote em uma string
    for(int i=0; i<SETDATA.length(); i++){
      received += (char) LoRa.read();
    }

    //Se o cabeçalho é o que esperamos
    if(received.equals(SETDATA)){
      //Fazemos a leitura dos dados
      LoRa.readBytes((uint8_t*)&data, sizeof(data));
      //Mostramos os dados no display
      showData();

      Serial.print("Publish message: ");
      //Criamos o json que enviaremos para o server mqtt
      const char *msg = createJsonString();
      Serial.println(msg);
      //Publicamos no tópico onde o servidor espera para receber 
      //e gerar o gráfico
      //client.publish(TOPIC_NAME, msg.c_str());
      //#define TOPIC_NAME "iot-2/evt/status/fmt/json"
         if (! Text1.publish(msg)) {
          Serial.println(F("Failed"));
        } else {
          Serial.println(F("OK!"));
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Protip: C doesn't have constructors.

Comment: It looks like a type mismatch. Can you show the code at and around Master:189?

Comment: Should `msg` be a `String` instead?

Comment: I just edited the post with the code as asked (Master:168 - 202)

Comment: Sorry about that, know it's not called a constructor but that's what I found out people would understand. 
Guess I have lots to learn yet ahah
Just a newbie :x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does look like a type mismatch. According to the compiler error, createJsonString() returns a string object. In C++ this is *not* the same as a character array. I'd suggest you take a moment to familiarize yourself with std::string, convert msg to a string object (as jxh) suggested and use the c_str() function to gain access to the character array.

[good description of string object](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/)